# Display the Storyboard UIViewController in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios

Is there anyway to rotate the UIViewController displayed on Storyboard as Landscape? By default it displays in a Portrait mode and wondering if there is anyway I can change that?

For iPhone app!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select UIViewController on storyboard.
2. tap on Utitlies button at top right corner to show Utilities panel.
3. Select **Attributes Inspector**.
4. Under **Simulated Metrics** section, you can change Orientation of UIViewController to Landscape.